# Cloud formation: Referencing a NAT gateway from a route gives Invalid id: "nat-0ad5d1c106dd74175"

Tags: networking, aws-cloudformation, nat

I have the following Cloud Formation configuration consisting of a subnet, route table/route, nat gateway and elastic IP:

```
  lambdaPointToIgwStaging:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Subnet'
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref mainVpc
      CidrBlock: '210.12.172.0/20'
      AvailabilityZone: eu-west-1b
  lambdaEipStaging:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::EIP'
    Properties:
    Domain: 'vpc'
  lambdaNatGatewayStaging:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::NatGateway'
    Properties:
      AllocationId: !GetAtt lambdaEipStaging.AllocationId
      SubnetId: !Ref lambdaPointToIgwStaging
  lambdaNatRoute:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Route'
    Properties:
      DestinationCidrBlock: '0.0.0.0/0'
      InstanceId: !Ref lambdaNatGatewayStaging
      RouteTableId: !Ref lambdaToNatStaging
    DependsOn: lambdaNatGatewayStaging
  lambdaToNatStaging:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::RouteTable'
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref mainVpc
```

It fails at the `lambdaNatRoute` creation, with the error `Invalid id: "nat-0ad5d1c106dd74175"` which is a thoroughly unhelpful error. I have tried a variety of dependsOn configurations but none seem to help. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Went through AWS support in the end and the answer was to use `NatGatewayId` instead of `InstanceId` in my Route definition:

```
  lambdaNatRoute:
   Type: 'AWS::EC2::Route'
   Properties:
     DestinationCidrBlock: '0.0.0.0/0'
     NatGatewayId: !Ref lambdaNatGatewayStaging
     RouteTableId: !Ref lambdaToNatStaging
```